# What is the origin of the word "Latin"?

Tags: etymology

I'm prompted by a question on the origin of the word English. Being English myself, I pretty much know that one.

But "Latin"? Why call it that?

As soon as this question crossed my mind, I realised it wouldn't exactly be an easy thing to Google, so I'm not even going to try. Surely someone here knows.

Comment: [Etymonline's entry on "latin"](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=Latin) also includes reference to [this instructive clip](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XbI-fDzUJXI).

Comment: Am intrigued to see someone voted to close querying the origin of the word "Latin". But not, apparently, the same for "English" on an earlier question!

Comment: First hit on google for "latin etymology": http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=Latin

Comment: @Hellion: Okay, I concede! I didn't bother because I expected the first 100 pages to be Latin origins for other words. Anyway, several people have voted for the answer, so I'm not going to delete the question. Apologies to anyone who thinks I've wasted time asking something I could have found out myself had I but had faith.

Comment: "Latin" may be "Italy" because initially writings were written from right to left

Comment: @Guest I assume you are thinking of Hebrew, there, not Latin.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Latin** comes from the latin word *Latinus* which means "*of Latium".

Latium is the ancient name of Lazio, one of the several regions Italy is divided into, and where Rome, the capital, is situated.

> <sup>**EDIT**: I uploaded another image that explains better the region and the position of Rome, the arrows and the names are mine. The other regions are indicated and the dots are the "capitals" (I don't know how it's in English) for each region.</sup>

[image: Map of modern Italy, indicating Roma and it surrounding region, Lazio]

This is what the Dictionary says about "Latium", just to be complete: "*An ancient region in west central Italy, west of the Apennines and south of the Tiber River. Settled during the early part of the 1st millennium bc by a branch of the Indo-European people known as the Latini, it was dominated by Rome by the end of the 4th century bc.*"

Comment: Ahah, I suppose so :D

Comment: Native speakers as I recall called their language "lingua latinae". Somebody who remembers more Latin than me could perhaps tell us whether strictly this means "language of Latium" or "language of the Latini".

Comment: As with ancient Greek, there seems to be uncertainty as to whether or how much these languages were indigenous to their earliest established locale, and how much they were influenced/brought in by foreign invaders, etc.

Comment: Nice little picture. I don't know much about art, but I know what I like! It does lend weight to the idea that much of the language might have effectively been "indigenous", being nestled in to the landscape like that.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Thanks! Actually I was looking for a better map with the names of the various regions and the main city for each of them... But in vain. :D

Comment: @Neil Coffey: Your Latin is a bit rusty, but maybe just a bit. *Lingua latina* is the correct phase and it means *the Latin tongue* or *the Latin language*. *Latinus/a/um* is the adjectival form of *Latium*.

Comment: @Ryan: I guess he meant "Lingua latinae" as in "Language of the Latini people", so "latinae" being a genitive might be correct, but it's been a while since last time I studied Latin, so I can't say that being 100% sure of it...

Comment: My Latin is *extremely* rusty, but I vaguely remembered that "latinae" was used. Now I Google, I see both so am confused...!

Comment: I will give you bonus points for a free-hand circle that shows the position of Rome inside its region.

Comment: @kiamla: It was not free-hand but I uploaded another picture which is better, I think. :)

Comment: @Alenanno It was a EL&U meme, but you deserve a vote for the excellent answer (which is what I will do when I can vote again).

Comment: @kiamla: I don't know that meme... Thanks for the future vote! :) @Fumble: Hopefully, you like this one better... :D

Comment: @NeilCoffey: I think "lingua Latinae" is simply a typing error. The only time you would encounter "Latinae" as a substantive is were it is short for "linguae Latinae"; but then there'd be no "lingua". So you might see "elementa Latinae" ("letters of Latin") or something like that. You could alternatively use "Latinum" to indicate the language. The Latin people is simply "Latini" ("the Latins"). There is no singular noun that denotes the people as far as I know, except "Latium", which metonymically uses the name of the region for its people.

Comment: Google hits give seven million "lingua Latina" v. nine thousand "lingua Latinae", if that says anything at all.

Comment: This map is a bit misleading. Ancient Latium did not extend "left" across the Tiber (where the Roma dot is) and not as far "up" above the Roma dot.  To the "right" of Roma to the end of the Grey section is about right.

Comment: @Oldcat If I remember correctly the map was supposed more to show the current map rather than the old region division. :P

Answer (score 2):

Mount Latium, after which the region got its name, was named after godess Lati/Lat.  The transcript "DEA LATI, LVCIUS URSEI" found on many temples, meaning "to goddess Lat I dedicate this“, referred to her. She was considered a Mother Goddess.

The Celts also worshipped her, the phrase "DIE LATI" meaning "to Lat" would be found on manu Celtic-built structures on the British Isles dedicated to her.

But the most well known people honored her were the Arabs who gave her the name Al-Lat, simply the feminine form in Arabic for "Allah" considerring her God's/Allah's wife, and being the mother Goddess the Mother of Baal/Pal/Apollo/Veles.

From the etymology it appears that her name comes from Arabic, worshipped later by other peoples, like many other Arabian Gods and Goddesses e.g. Assyra/Aphrodite, and Baal/Apollo and Naila and Isaf.

Comment: That sounds like you made it up. Do you have any references?

Comment: What part do you suppose i made up?

Comment: I've never heard of anything like that before so I'm just curious  and would like to know where to read up more about it.

Comment: *al Lat* is an ancient Arabian goddess, and is mentioned in the Quran[53:19], and the Hadith in relation to the Satanic Verses. She was part of a trinity of sorts.

Answer (score 0):

The Latins were the people living around the city of Rome. They were "absorbed" politically by the better-organized dwellers of that city, who nevertheless adopted much of their language and culture, and made them among the earliest "citizens" of the new Empire.

Put another way, the Latins "merged" with the Romans, but their language (or much of it) survived the "merger."

Answer (score 0):

Connecting Latium (and thereby Latin) to a pre-Islamic goddess mentioned in the Coran (written in the 7th Century AD) is highly creative (even if not respectful to linguists, to Muslims and to Romans). So is the mention of this "Mount Latium". I live in Monterotondo, not far from Rome, please do not hesitate to give me the location of this mountain, unknown to all the people in the region, and I will drive there immediately ! Baci da bellissima lazio.

Oh, by the way :
Lătĭum , ii, n. 2. lătus; Sanscr. root prath-, to spread or widen; cf. Lat. later, etc.; prop., the plains or flat-land; “by the ancients referred to latēre, because here Saturnus lay concealed from his son,” Ov. F. 1, 238; Verg. A. 8, 322; Arn. 4, 143; Lact. 1, 13; “or to Latinus,” the name of the mythical king, Varr. L. L. 5, § 32 Müll.,
a country of Italy, in which Rome was situated

in  Charlton T. Lewis et Charles Short, A Latin Dictionary, Clarendon Press, Oxford, 1879

Answer (score -2):

I have read that the word Latin is derived from latens, meaning 'hidden', & 'lut', meaning 'veil'. Source quoted as being a book by Pierre Sabak, a comparative linguist & symbologist.